# JBoss tools for JSP: Make content assist work for Bootstrap "class" as in HTML Editor

Tags: autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, content-assist, jboss-tools

I am working in JBoss Tools editors for HTML and JSP pages in Eclipse Luna.

One interesting thing I found about the different way these two editors work, is that some time they can auto-complete, but sometimes JBoss JSP editors fails. More precisely, when it comes to the "class" attribute which come with Bootstrap 3, the HTML editor works while JSP editor fails. Even though I can open the `.jsp` file with JBoss HTML editor, the problem persists.

Is there some way to fix this?? They work consistently in some other cases, like this:

When I have a `<form>`, and I type `enctype="` or even `enc`, in both editors when you press `alt + /`, you will have `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, which is amazing.

I attach GIF to show this strange behaviour:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alexey Kazakov I have checked my `login.jsp` page and I found that `bootstrap.css` is not introduced in this page, but in other pages, `jsp` as well as `html`, this file is introduced in `<head>` part. So the editor is not working wrongly, it's my fault.

So JBoss Tools stay to be fantastic. ;)