# make jboss editor read external bootstrap 3 css style and auto complete

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jboss, tiles

I asked a similar question here: 
[JBoss tools for JSP: Make content assist work for Bootstrap "class" as in HTML Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293627/jboss-tools-for-jsp-make-content-assist-work-for-bootstrap-class-as-in-html-e)

In which I realized that JBoss web page editor is able to read CSS styles and render them in the `preview` tab, and auto-complete with correct suggestions, only if the `.css` file is included explicitly in the `<head>` part of the webpage you are editing, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
```

But, in another project I am working at, we are using Tiles, and every single web page we create, inherits `general-layout` in the `tiles-definition.xml` like this:

```
<definition name="somepage" extends="generalLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body"   value="/WEB-INF/...../somepage.tile.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="script" value="/WEB-INF...../somepage.script.tile.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

`<link>` part is included in the `general-layout` page and not in every web page, so the JBoss web page editor cannot render them when we code, and no auto-completion.

Is there any way to config the editor to force it read some `.css` files in the project, so we can see the effect on-the-fly and to have the auto-completion?

Thanks.

Comment: hey @FaithReaper could you get your answer..

Comment: Sorry but I found it impossible at least now.